Is it appropriate to ask about wildlife that I am deliberately trying to attract or care for in some way?
The on-topic guide states that we should only ask about domestic animals and not wildlife. However, what about wildlife that we're deliberately trying to attract or care for?
In my case, I wanted to ask a question about how to attract hummingbirds to my feeder given that my neighbor also has a hummingbird feeder and I think that all of the hummingbirds are visiting her feeder instead of mine.
Is it appropriate to ask such a question here? If not, is there a better site for this, or is there some way that I can make the question on-topic somehow?

I don't particularly think that's undesirable subject material, and we do have the occational questions on cottontails.  Maybe https://gardening.stackexchange.com would be a possible fit, and asking 'generically' on meta.se where to ask would have good leads too.

See also https://gardening.stackexchange.com/search?q=bird+feeder

A question about birds fits right in the grey area. As a mod I wouldn't close it immediately, but it may gert closed by community votes. It might also get upvotes and good answers. Always hard to predict.
